# Fetch all repos from github on specific topic using api v3

Tags: python, json, api, github

I am trying to fetch data of all repositories from GitHub on the topic of nodejs. But currently, they have a limit of showing only the first 1000 data with pagination of 30 repos on each page.

I have already tried fetching data with below code.

```
import requests


for i in range(1,50):
    try:
        url="https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=topic:nodejs&page="+str(i)
        response=requests.request(url=url,method='GET')
        proj=response.json()
        data=get_data(proj)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

Here `get_data()` is called to get internal data of the repo in json.

Is there any workaround to pass that 1000 limit or another way to get repos for only a specific topic?

PS: I am using search api currently.

Comment: Use multiple API tokens?

Comment: Do you have any idea how many repositories GitHub hosts? You're talking about a _ton_ of data. Why do you need to do this?

Comment: I just need only on the topic of nodejs and I found there are about 60K of them on GitHub. And about what, I am working on a project, nothing suspicious.

Comment: @DroidX86 using multiple API tokens doesn't help. GitHub provides result maybe using LIMIT 1000 somewhere in their query. It's not about rate limit but fetching more result.